# What does marginal revenue actually mean in this case?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, applications

The problem states that,

`The total revenue in Dollars received from the sale of x units of a product is given by`

$D(x) = 3x^2 + 36x + 5$

`Find the marginal revenue, when x = 5, where by marginal revenue we mean the rate of change of total revenue with respect to the number of items sold at an instant.`

So, I solved this by simply calculating the derivative of the function with respect to x. Which is

$6x + 36$

And plugged in x = 5 which returned me with 66 dollars of marginal revenue.

So what does this value actually signify? I googled marginal revenue and it said that,

`The revenue gained by producing one additional unit of a product or service.`

So if I have sold 1 unit and then sold 5 more units, that is 6 units then the extra revenue made should be equal to 66 dollars right? But putting x = 1 and x = 6 for D(x) gives me 44 and 329 respectively and the difference of both is 285.

So can someone please explain me what does 66 actually signify here? And how can I explicitly obtain this value by using some value(s) of x in D(x)?

Answer (score 1):

The revenue obtained from selling five units is $\ 3\cdot5^2 +$$36\cdot5+$$5=$$260\ $ dollars. The revenue obtained from selling six units is $\ 3\cdot6^2 +36\cdot6+5=329\ $ dollars. Thus, the marginal revenue for the  sixth unit is $\ 329-360=69\ $ dollars.  This is not equal to the derivative at $\ x=5\ $ because the derivative of the revenue increeases in value  from $66$ to $72$ over the interval from $\ x=5\ $ to $\ x=6\ $.

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly calculated the marginal revenue to be $66.

The marginal revenue is the rate of change of total revenue with respect to the number of units sold, i.e Marginal revenue= $\frac{Change in revenue}{Change in quantity}$.

So if 10 units sell \$7, resulting in total revenues of \$70; 11 units sell at \$6.50, resulting in total revenues of \$71.50. This indicates the marginal revenue of the 11th unit is \$1.50 (\$71.50 - \$70).

Answer (score 0):

What you should compare is

- the value of the derivative at $x=5$, or $66$;
- the price increment from $x=5$ to $x=5+1$, or $69$.

These two numbers differ because the derivative is an approximation of the first-order difference (or conversely). This is not a true problem when all you need is an order of magnitude.

---

For a quadratic law $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, the first-order difference is

$$\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}1=2ax+a+b$$

while the derivative is

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=2ax +b$$ where $h$ is "infinitely small".